# Measure the overall network usage

Tags: wireless-networking, bandwidth

Can anyone please tell me how can I measure the network data. For example, my office wifi is used by me and 5 of my employees. Can I check the amount of data being downloaded from individual PC?

Thank you for your time.

Regards

Comment: that is not you can do with a regular cheap wifi router. However some routers have SNMP - simple network management protocol implemented. You can access such router on a specific port and get some data like statistical usage of bandwith and so on.

Comment: You could do this with `iftop` if your router would be on Linux. You did not specified what kind of router you have...

Comment: @mnmnc Thank you for your reply. I am using Beetel 450 TC1 ADSL2+ Router. I have installed iftop but it gave me the following error : 
eth2: You don't have permission to capture on that device.

Answer (score 0):

Practical would be a Switch/WLAN Device which does Support [Netflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netflow).
No a snorkeling tool. Imo neither uncritical in regard to privacy.

Comment: I am using Beetel 450TC1 ADSL 2+ router. This is installed at my office. I googled and I can see that it does support Netflow, but can you please tell me an open source solution to it?